# Nativescript Android - buttons not reacting after app goes go background

Tags: android, nativescript

I have a strange problem with my Nativescript-App.
It's an app with a tap-bar.

On Android, when the app goes into background mode, after it's reactivated, the buttons on the current page don't react anymore.
I have to switch to another tab, go back and then the buttons are working again.

Any ideas what could cause this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding some debug statements in the loaded event handler, as it should fire each time you return to a page.

Comment: It does fire every time. But the problem still persists.